# Using the standard gamePad code, not finding sound files even though the path name is correct?

Tags: html5-audio, gamepad-api

**Using the standard gamePad code**, *not* finding sound files even though the path name is correct?

I have definitely researched this question. For sure, I have found code on SO claiming to solve this dilemma, but this published code doesn't.

I am **successfully** finding the sound file using Preview under BBEdit's "Markup" Menu. But, **the oh-oh surfaces** when running my game on my commercial Server.

I am even **successful** when using keypress code is activated -- local on my Mac **and** on the Server.

The **failure** is when I am using the external Server to run my gamePad code to find the sound file when all my source code is loaded onto my Server. In this case, the sound does not play.

**FILE HIERARCHY**

```
games folder
   Game_1 folder
      game1.html
      Game_Support folder
         audio folder
         js folder
```

**HTML**

```
<body onload="doBodyOnLoad()">
```

**JS:**

```
function doBodyOnLoad() {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // ... //

    });   // $(document).ready

}   // doBodyOnload


function setupKeypresses() {

    $(document).keydown(function(evt) {
        
        let code = evt.keyCode || evt.which;

        // for example:
        if (code === "R")
        {
            movePaddleRight();  // this will call ouch() below
        }
            
    });
    
}   // setupKeypresses


function PlaySound(id, src) {

    let theSound = new Audio();
    theSound.src = src;
    
    theSound.play();
    
}   // PlaySound


function ouch() {

    updateScore(--thisScore);
    
    // even the absolute path doesn't work ?
//  var theSnd = "http://lovesongforever.com/games/Game_1/Game_1_Support/audio/explosion.mp3";
    var theSnd = "Game_1_Support/audio/explosion.mp3";
    PlaySound("audioPlaceHolder", theSnd);
            
    // fade either the whole Board (okay), or just the Paddle (not! so much)
    doFade("#gameBoard");   // doFade("#gameBoard > #gamePaddle") [not ready for Prime Time]

}   // ouch
```

Thanks bunches for your patience with me!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're trying to autoplay an Audio element without user interaction to initiate the audio.

> Firefox expresses a blocked `play()` call to JavaScript by rejecting the promise returned by `HTMLMediaElement.play()` with a `NotAllowedError`. All major browsers which block autoplay express a blocked play via this mechanism. In general, the advice for web authors when calling `HTMLMediaElement.play()`, is to *not assume* that calls to `play()` will always succeed, and to always handle the promise returned by `play()` being rejected.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/02/firefox-66-to-block-automatically-playing-audible-video-and-audio/

I think it will work if you click or tap on the page first. Gamepad button presses may work for this too depending on the implementation.

Comment: **(1)** But I am using my Gamepad to move game pieces and when it hits the Wall the audio plays on my local Browser when I run the code on my iMac. **(2)** When I run the code with the Gamepad on the commercial Server, the sound won’t play **unless** I first use my Keyboard to force the game pieces to hit the Wall and play the sound. Then even on the commercial Server the sound will play. SO, the problem is isolated to just using the Gamepad to move pieces. Using Keypresses to move pieces that hit obstacles works all day long.

Comment: The fact that the sound plays if I first use the keyboard to deliberately hit the obstacle (Wall) and **then** use the Gamepad to hit the wall. It's almost as if the use of the keyboard helps to find the audio and then every thing works, even the Gamepad. BTW, I took your clue about autoplay and added **theSound.autoplay = true;** to my PlaySound code. Did not help.

Comment: Which browsers are you using on your iMac and on your server?

Comment: **Safari** (no sound just with Gamepad *unless* I first press a key to force the sound to play), **Chrome** sound plays with Gamepad -- but has other problems, **Firefox** fails with the Gamepad API 100% AFAIKT